# How can I fix this while loop?

Tags: python

the goal of the program is to multiply the count times the value of hamburger. I put the count in a while loop but every time i run the program it freezes and doesn't execute.

```
def input1():
  menu = input("""
  hamburger--:  """)
  loop = input("Would you like to add another Food: (y/n)?")


  return menu, loop


def calc():
    menu, loop = input1()
    cost = 0
    full_menu = {'h': 1.25, 'f': .75, 's': 1.0}

    while menu in full_menu:
        cost = full_menu[menu]
        cost2 = 0
        cost2 += 1
        if loop == "y":
         menu, loop = input1()
         calc()
        if loop == "n":
         print(cost2 * cost )





def main():
  menu, loop = input1()
  calc()

main()
```

Comment: Can you make sure the indentation is correct in the question. For example, your `if` statements in the `calc` function, they should probably be in the while loop

Comment: I see a few issues with this code. For one thing, you already call `menu, loop = input1()` inside `calc()`, so you don't need to call it again in `main()`, especially since you then don't do anything with it. Second, you declare `cost2` as `0` and add 1 to it every time you loop, so it will only ever equal 1

Comment: The real issue I see is that you recursively call `calc()`, which means inside each loop you create a new loop, which creates a new loop inside it, and so on and so forth. This is not a good use of recursion. A recursive function should take in arguments that are incremented each time it is run, so that you actually change something. You've created infinite recursion.

Comment: How would fix the calc() so it doesn't continuously make a new function.

Comment: Easiest way is to _NOT_ call `calc()` inside of `calc()`. Instead, just do all of the operations inside your `while` loop

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to make this work with recursion, but since you don't state that you are trying to use it, it's simpler without. You can skip the first function altogether, and do all of your operations in a single while loop:

```
def calc():
    cost = 0
    full_menu = {'h': 1.25, 'f': .75, 's': 1.0}
    item='n/a'
    print('Hamburger: h\nFries: f\nSoda: s\n')
    while item:
        item = input("What would you like to order? (h/f/s or type 'q' to quit)").lower()
        if item in full_menu:
            cost += full_menu[item]
        else:
            break
    print("Your bill is ${}!".format(cost))
```